# Ruby - Check for String and then Take Substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an attribute that I expect to often begin with `"category-"`.

For example:

```
@category = "category-ruby-on-rails"
```

How can I check if `@category` begins with `"category-"` and then, if it does, get only the value after `"category-"` (i.e. `"ruby on rails"` in this example)?

Comment: You could check, will they always be `some-words-separated-by-hyphen`? no matter if this starts with `category-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways that use a regular expression. (In both, `nil` is returned if there is no match.)

```
str = "category-ruby-on-rails"

str[/(?<=\Acategory-).*/]
  #=> "ruby-on-rails"

str[/\Acategory-(.*)/, 1]
  #=> "ruby-on-rails"
```

`(?<=\Acategory-)` is a *positive lookbehind*. It means that `"category-"` must be matched at the beginning of the string (`\A`), but it is not part of the match that is returned.

`(.*)` saves `.*` into capture group 1. The second argument of the instance method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) is the capture group whose contents are to be retrieved and returned by the method.

We could also use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
s = str.gsub(/\Acategory-/, '')
  #=> "ruby-on-rails"
```

but would need to check if there had been a match. For example,

```
s == str
  #=> false (meaning the match was performed)
```

There are many other ways to do this, including some that don't use a regular expression.

```
s = "category-"
str[s.size..-1] if str.start_with?(s)
  #=> "ruby-on-rails"

str = "division-ruby-on-rails"
str[s.size..-1] if str.start_with?(s)
  #=> nil
```

Comment: It seems that you can solve everything with regexp. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if @category starts with "category-" if so you just split your string, drop its first element and join

```
 result = false
 if @category.start_with?("category-")
    result = @category.split("-").drop(1).join("-")
 end
```

The "one-line" version :

```
 result = @category.start_with?("category-") ? @category.split("-").drop(1).join("-") : false
```